# [Playwright]: fonts appear gray in webkit headless

Tags: javascript, playwright

When taking a snapshot in webkit headless, the fonts appear grayed out in comparison to headful.

In headful it looks like this:
[image: Font in headfull]

In headless it looks like this:
[image: Font in headless]

The code is relatively simple - just load a page.
The page loads the fonts from `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap`

Had anyone encountered this issue? What can cause this?